# EntireRow.Delete is only deleting every other row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a for loop which goes through all of the values in a table and should delete every row that says no, however it is only deleting every other row. I put a column which was just numbers 1-30 and I clearly saw 11,13,15,17,19,21,etc said no but were not deleted. Why is it only deleting every other row?

edit - looping through it backwards has the same problem

```
currRow = 1
currCell = Cells(currRow, 21).Value

For i = 1 To 30
    If currCell = "no" Then
        Rows(currRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    currRow = currRow + 1
    currCell = Cells(currRow, 21).Value
Next i
```

Comment: You need to loop backward using `For i = 30 to 1 step -1`

Comment: This has been asked and answered approximately a million times. However I can't be bothered to find an example, so I'll just answer. Go from bottom to top, or if you delete, don't increment i. See, deleting a row also pulls all the rows below it up, so row 10 will become row 9, and it will get skipped when i goes from 9 to 10.

Comment: Looping bottom to top will work, but is the single most inefficient thing you can do. Use `Union` to merge all the rows you want to delete into a single range, then do one single `myUnionedRange.EntireRow.Delete` call.

Comment: Also note, `If currCell = "no"` will blow up with a *type mismatch* if `Cells(currRow, 21).Value` contains an error value (assuming `currCell` is a `Variant`, implicit or not). Errors can't be compared to a string or number literal.

Answer (score 2):

You can step backwards and delete the rows. Also, your method in your `For...Next` statement is off.

You are saying `If currCell = "no"`, but `currCell` doesn't update until after you check for row `i`.

Just completely get rid of that variable.

Also, get rid of `currRow` variable as well.

```
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

For i = 30 To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 21).Value = "no" Then
        ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

---

You do not have to go backwards. Create a special range object to keep track of the rows to delete, then delete them all at once:

```
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, delRng As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

For i = 1 To 30
    If ws.Cells(i, 21).Value = "no" Then
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = ws.Rows(i)
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(delRng, ws.Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I look at his code, then all the variables inside the `For` loop are constant, so `Rows(currRow).EntireRow.Delete` is equivalent to `Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete` and so 30 consecutive rows should have been deleted. What do I miss?

Comment: Ah... sorry. His lousy indentation got me off guard.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yeah it caught me off guard as well

Comment: @K.Davis I ran your second code against some test data, would not work, could you check it?

Comment: @GMalc59 I accidentally had `rows(21)` instead of `rows(i)`.

Comment: @K.Davis i thought that was it, but wanted to be sure, outstanding code.